# Firebase cloud function cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to create user profile in realtime database after google login in my android app.
So, I have tried this code in cloud function to do it.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.AddAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    const user = event.data;
    var userObject = {
        displayName : user.displayName,
        email : user.email,
        photoUrl : user.photoURL,
        createdOn : user.metadata.createdAt
    };
    admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set(userObject);
});
```

after deploying this code i tested in my app.
and it is showing error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
at exports.AddAccount.functions.auth.user.onCreate.event (/srv/index.js:10:22)
at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
at /worker/worker.js:825:24
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

The method [`onCreate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation) returns a user object, not an event with data:

```
exports.AddAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  const userObject = {
    displayName : user.displayName,
    email : user.email,
    photoUrl : user.photoURL,
    createdOn : user.metadata.createdAt
  };

  return admin.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set(userObject);
});
```

---

About the other error. It's not allowed to import a property with value `undefined`. This should either be defined, `null` or not put at all.

The reason you are getting the error, is because the [`metadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userrecordmetadata) object has the property [`creationTime`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_auth_.userrecordmetadata.html#creationtime).

So to be safe, you can do it like this:

```
const userObject = {
  displayName : user.displayName,
  email : user.email,
  photoUrl : user.photoURL,
  createdOn : user.metadata.creationTime || null
};
```

It's advisable to read the documentation and API well, before pushing a new function, this will save you time :)

Comment: i have tried your code but it is show new error.                                                         
                `Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.GvnKc7CF1mMZRzSA27fJ491tLID3.createdOn'
    .......`

Comment: @RachitSingh I've updated my answer to help you with your other error

Comment: thanks for your help. profile created in database but is showing error `Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
` why?

Comment: That's now a completely different problem.  You need to return a promise from the function when all the async work is complete.  This is not an optional step.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions